# Are there any experiments that prove or disprove Extended Electrodynamics or are there any theoretical inconsistencies in EED?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity

I have come across an article https://www.mdpi.com/2073-8994/12/12/2110, that promotes a theory of electromagnetism that deviates from Maxwell's theory. It is claimed in the paper that this alternative theory, which they call Extended Electrodynamics, can be derived from a Lagranian proposed by Stueckelberg.

Are there any experiments  that prove or disprove Extended Electrodynamics, or are there any theoretical inconsistencies in EED?

Comment: I believe the burden is on new theories to show how they comply with experiments, not the other way around.

Comment: That paper may be interesting to read and think about, but be careful, it makes some grandiose claims and looks suspect. There are millions of ways to extend electromagnetic theory, some are natural (like rejection of Poynting's expression as  correct energy expressions in case of point particles), but some are entirely speculative (like various Lagrangians with novel terms, or promoting EM potentials to unique measurable quantities). Showing that new EM theory is better than the standard one is almost an impossible task, for various reasons.

Comment: I am not competent to opine on the paper but I think the question relates to one of the most interesting puzzle in classical EM and that must have puzzled everybody who has studied it ever since Maxwell. I freely admit that I will die believing it in the back of my mind, way back, that one day somebody will "regularize" $\mathbf A$ and will be acknowledged as the real thing just as entropy is *the* real thing and not heat.